# How do I parse this json data in view laravel

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

this is my view:

```
    <body>
      <h1>Vista - teck</h1>
       <p> {{ $resp }} </p>
   </body>
```

the output in view:

```
{ "Recinto":99, "Nombre":"CINEMAX", "Direccion":"42 Miller Alley", "CPostal":"91103", "Localidad":"PASADENA", "Provincia":"CALIFORNIA", "Pais":"ESPAÑA", "GoogleMaps":"42 Miller Alley,Pasadena, CA 91103,EE. UU.", "TelCompra":"626-639-226", "TelTaquillas":"626-639-2260", "TelOficinas":"626-639-2260", "Fidelize":1, "FidelizeFormato":"XXXXX", "FidelizeUsaPuntos":0, "FidelizeUsaBonos":0, "FidelizeLoginDescuentos":0, "FidelizeLogin":"", "FidelizeRegistro":"../fidelizacion/socioalta", "URLSecure":"seguro.reservaentradas.com/pago/", "SinProximamente":1, "MostrarQR":1, "Lista":0, "MaxEntradas":16, "EnvioLocEmail":1, "Subdominio":"cinepruebas", "NombreGuarderia":"Mini Lys", "DescripcionGuarderia":"Lalalalalala", "PrecioGuarderia":3, "SinTaquillaFisica":0, "CajerosDisponibles":0,"UUID":"76e29a57-1edf-4997-80d9-e15f5de67923", "Eventos":[] ,"ProximosEventos":[{ "Id":282, "Titulo":"300: EL ORIGEN DE UN IMPERIO", "TituloOriginal":"", "Duracion":60, "EsPelicula":1, "Estreno":"3/7/2014", "CalificacionId":6, "Calificacion":"No recomendada para menores de 16 años", "Genero":"", "Sinopsis":"", "Imagen":"http://cines.reservaentradas.com/cinepruebas/obj/LCinesD_dat/eventos/.jpg", "Video":"", "Formato":""},{ "Id":4, "Titulo":"BAD TEACHER", "TituloOriginal":"", "Duracion":100, "EsPelicula":1, "Estreno":"7/8/2011", "CalificacionId":4, "Calificacion":"No recomendada para menores de 7 años", "Genero":"", "Sinopsis":"Elizabeth Halsey es una profesora a la que su profesión le importa una M Es malhablada, despiadada, y salvajemente inapropiada. Bebe, se coloca, y su única meta es casarse con un hombre adinerado para poder dejar su trabajo como profesora de instituto. Cuando su prometido la deja, desarrolla un plan para enamorar al rico y guapo profesor suplente, pero para ello tendrá que competir contra una colega demasiado enérgica, Amy, y combatir las insinuaciones del irreverente profesor de gimnasia.", "Imagen":"http://cines.reservaentradas.com/cinepruebas/obj/LCinesD_dat/eventos/JPG00017.jpg", "Video":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZGwp0xls1nc", "Formato":""},{ "Id":7, "Titulo":"CONAN EL BARBARO", "TituloOriginal":"", "Duracion":80, "EsPelicula":1, "Estreno":"8/19/2011", "CalificacionId":0, "Calificacion":"", "Genero":"", "Sinopsis":"", "Imagen":"http://cines.reservaentradas.com/cinepruebas/obj/LCinesD_dat/eventos/.jpg", "Video":"", "Formato":""},{ "Id":1, "Titulo":"LOS PITUFOS", "TituloOriginal":"", "Duracion":80, "EsPelicula":1, "Estreno":"8/1/2011", "CalificacionId":1, "Calificacion":"Para todos los públicos", "Genero":"", "Sinopsis":"", "Imagen":"http://cines.reservaentradas.com/cinepruebas/obj/LCinesD_dat/eventos/JPG0000l.jpg", "Video":"", "Formato":""}]}
```

And I want to see something so

```
Recinto: 99
Nombre: CINEMAX
Direccion : 42 Miller Alley
ETC.....
```

EDIT: 
In my controller

```
public function GetApiExt(){
$cliente = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://cinemax.reserv.com/']);

$respuesta = $cliente->request('GET','index?', 
        [
            'query' => ['recinto' => '99', 
                        'key' => 'apikey',
                       ]
        ])->getBody();

return view('apitest')->with('resp',$respuesta);
```

First of all many thanks in advance. and sorry for my English.

Comment: How do you get the `$resp` variable?

Comment: from here. My controller --> return view('apitest')->with('resp',$respuesta);

Comment: @jay-blanchard Where this duplicate? Nothing to do man!

Comment: modify your `$respuesta` before passing to view.
`$parsed = json_decode($respuesta);`

and in view
 `@foreach($parsed as $key => $val)
        {{$key}} : {{$val}} <br>
    @endforeach`

Comment: Not found @Sid. :(

Comment: you also need to edit the last line of your function like 
`return view ('apitest')->with('parsed', $parsed)` and then it should work

Comment: Yes @Sid I do,  but dont found. Thank u  bro. Very stranger. I upload the source code on github. I send link.